insmod: ERROR: could not insert module test.ko: Invalid module format
Am trying to insert a test module but getting an error like:
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module test.ko: Invalid module format

I have checked the kernel version and architecture: both the things are matches correctly and tried with uninstall and reinstall the headers but still same issue.
I have tried following things:


uname -r
5.15.0-52-generic



modinfo test.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     0D9203C0EB39345D74EBCEF
vermagic:       5.15.0-52-generic SMP mod_unload modversions



uname -m
x86_64



file test.ko
test.ko: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
BuildID[sha1]=274b1d760d4234e583f5abfc894f27fcc5c04ec1, with 
debug_info, not stripped



How can I insert my module?

After failed insmod you should be able to obtain more detailed reason of the error by inspecting the output of dmesg.

Any other output if insmod -v test.ko?

dmesg output: [81510.155861] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000007f54b83, val ffffffffc15f6000

insmod -v test.ko for this am getting invalid operation: insmod: invalid option -- 'v'

Looks like you have something wrong when compile your kernel module. Please, add details to your question post: Which commands do you run when compile the module. How have you obtained the kernel headers.
